# Regular expression to find lvalue and rvalue in source code (ignore == )

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am using the regular expression `dEF\w+\(\w+\)=.*?;` in order to find patterns of the following form:

```
dEFPFC(pATREF)=dIDOSSEGPfc(pIDOSSeg);
dEFTur(pATREF)=dIDOSSEGTurnaround(pIDOSSeg);
```

The problem is that it also taking into account patterns that have `==`. I don't want that.

this pattern `dEFOriDate(pNextEF)==dEFDesDate(pATREF));` should be ignored because it has `==`.

I tried using `dEF\w+\(\w+\)={1}.*?;` but it didn't work

---

I tested the regular expression on https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative `(?!=)` [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after `=`:

```
dEF\w+\(\w+\)=(?!=).*?;
              ^^^^^
```

The `(?!=)` lookahead will fail a match if the `=` (matched with `=`) is followed with another `=`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3Tu0Z/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could match one equals sign and after that not an equals sign `[^=]` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

[`dEF\w+\(\w+\)=[^=].*?;`](https://regex101.com/r/KjDiIi/1)